# Ansible: source a local file and use its defined variables in task

Tags: docker, variables, ansible, yaml, conditional-statements

I have a ini style file with docker names, users and versions:

sourcefile.txt:

```
APP1_IMAGE=register:5000/app1:2.1-b4
APP2_IMAGE=register:4000/app2:3.8-b10
REGISTRY_URL=register.local
USER=%user%
```

Now I want to source the file and use the definitions as variables in other roles.

---

What I tried:
I can only print the file and not us it, only echoing the file.

*role.yml* file

```
vars:
    sourceinput: "{{ lookup('file','sourcefile.txt') }}"
  roles:
    - { role: roles/sourcefile }
```

*task.yml* file

```
- name: Debug sourcefile.txt
  debug: '{{ item }}'
  with_items: '{{ sourceinput }}'
```

---

What I like to do something as this:

```
var: sourcefile
with_items:
      - {{ APP2_IMAGE.version }}
```

or to be used as a global variable in the playbook

```
when {{ APP2_IMAGE.appversion }} is app2:3.8-b10
when {{ APP1_IMAGE }} is defined
```

Like in a command:

```
$ docker login %user%
$ docker pull {{REGISTRY_URL}}/{{APP2_IMAGE.VERSION}}
$ docker pull register.local/app2:3.8-b10
```

Im lost in the documentation about loops, vars and conditionals.

Comment: Hi tapestreamer welcome to SO. Are you aware of [the `ini` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/ini_lookup.html)?

Comment: Yes, but changing it will affect other applications.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to import variables from an external file using the `vars_files` attribute, but the files must be in a YAML or JSON format.

A YAML format is very similar to the INI format you show, simply replace the = with : and add a space:

```
APP1_IMAGE: register:5000/app1:2.1-b4
APP2_IMAGE: register:4000/app2:3.8-b10
REGISTRY_URL: register.local
USER: %user%
```

Does your file need to be in an INI format? If so, the only other solution I can see is using [ansible.builtin.ini](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ini_lookup.html) to read variables, but this could be cumbersome. Here's a basic example:

```yaml
  vars: 
    app1_image: "{{ lookup('ini', 'APP1_IMAGE file=demo.txt') }}"
    app2_image: "{{ lookup('ini', 'APP2_IMAGE file=demo.txt') }}"
    registry_url: "{{ lookup('ini', 'REGISTRY_URL file=demo.txt') }}"
    user: "{{ lookup('ini', 'USER file=demo.txt') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: app1
      debug: msg={{ app1_image }}
    - name: app2
      debug: msg={{ app2_image }}
    - name: registry_url
      debug: msg={{ registry_url }}
    - name: user
      debug: msg={{ user }}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
TASK [app1] *********************************************************************
ok: [my_test_server] => {
    "msg": "register:5000/app1:2.1-b4"
}

TASK [app2] *********************************************************************
ok: [my_test_server] => {
    "msg": "register:4000/app2:3.8-b10"
}

TASK [registry_url] *************************************************************
ok: [my_test_server] => {
    "msg": "register.local"
}

TASK [user] *********************************************************************
ok: [my_test_server] => {
    "msg": "some_user"
}
```

In terms of how you wanted to use the variables (i.e. `{{ APP2_IMAGE.version }}`) I'm afraid that isn't possible. Since your variable in the INI file is just a string, Ansible has no automatic way to break that down into an object, it can only be read as a string.

You could potentially break it down into a complex object manually using regexes, but this is again cumbersome. I would seriously consider switching to using your variables in a YAML file, and only consider these options as a last resort.

Comment: Yes, it would need to stay that format I guess.

Comment: Hi @tapestreamer I've updated my answer above with another potential solution.